# How to integrate EGL (not EGAL) with iOS (C & Obj-C)

Tags: android, ios, c, opengl-es, egl

I'm currently working on an iOS port of an Android app built on top of a custom standard C library that uses what appears to be EGL, GLES, GLES2, OpenGL, OpenGL ES, OpenGL ES2.
Unfortunately, I have no experience with working with the above technologies, particularly pertaining to EGL and OpenGL. I understand that EGL is the interface between OpenGL ES and the underlying native platform window system as well that iOS has adapted EGL into EAGL to support Cocoa's rules.

The resources I've found mostly discuss EGL and android but does not mention much about EGL integration with C and iOS specifically, but a lot of it came back to obj-C and EAGL.

1. How do I support EGL in C on an iOS (obj-C) platform? Is EGL even necessary for OpenGL?
2. Where/which source can I retrieve the EGL library from? I have read that different vendors provide different versions (unfortunately for unknown reasons, the android version has #include  but the actual source file isn't found among the project files)
3. If EGL cannot be supported on the iOS platform as a C-level integration, how would can I adapt EAGL for my use case?

Below is some pieces of sample code that I'm working through, unfortunately a lot of the EGL references are undefined, and I have attempted to use this library here (https://github.com/davidandreoletti/libegl) to fill the gaps, but apparently there are a lot of references still undefined else, such as eglChooseConfig, eglGetDisplay, eglinitialize.

```
//GraphicsDisplay.h
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>

...

static EGLDisplay eglDisplay
static EGLSurface eglSurface
static EGLContext eglContext
```

```
//GraphicsDisplay.c
#include "GraphicsDisplay.h"

STATUS_CODE getScreenSize(UNIT16 *width, UNIT16 *height) {
  EGLint displayWidth;
  EGLint displayHeight;

  //check if there's a screen
  if(eglDisplay == EGL_NO_DISPLAY && eglSurface == EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
    return OK;
  }

  if(eglQuerySurface(eglDisplay, eglSurface, EGL_WIDTH, displayWidth) == EGL_FALSE) {
    return FAIL;
  }

  *width = (UNIT16)displayWidth;

  if(eglQuerySurface(eglDisplay, eglSurface, EGL_HEIGHT, displayHeight) == EGL_FALSE) {
    return FAIL;
  }

  *height = (UNIT16)displayHeight;

  return OK;
}

STATUS_CODE EGLInitialize() {
  EGLint format;
  EGLint numconfigs;
  EGLConfig config;

  EGLint attribs[] = { EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 4, EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 4, EGL_RED_SIZE, 4, EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT, EGL_NONE };
  EGLint attribList[] = { EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL_NONE };

  eglDisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
  eglInitialize(eglDisplay, 0, 0);

  eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, attribs, &config, 1 &numConfigs);
  eglGetConfigAttrib(eglDisplay, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format);

  ... etc...
}
```

Any insights into this would help.
Code examples would be most comprehensive and appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the short answer is "you can't" - EAGL is the iOS version of the EGL-like functionality, so you'll have to port to using EAGL on iOS.

There are lots of iOS EAGL + OpenGL ES tutorials on the web which can teach you how to get started with the EAGL API; it's not simple enough to warrant an attempt at an answer here.

Comment: I agree. I would add that GLKView tutorials are probably the thing to look for. It's roughly analogous to Android's GLSurfaceView in that it does most of the setup boiler plate for you and meets the needs of the vast majority of use cases.